# what can i do to fix getting syntax error at or near " "

Tags: c#, psql

I have tried a lot of options from guides and no one of them works, it shows syntax error or column id does not exist

```
try
{              
    conn.Open();
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    sql = "UPDATE public.demand SET city = @city, demand = @demand WHERE demand_id = @id";

    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", citytext.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demandupdate", demandtext.Text.ToString());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Show us the error output. Also you are not adding `@id` in the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> it shows syntax error or column id doesnt not exist

You are not adding a value in the parameters for the `@id`.

Add this line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Comment: @Stenders can you provide the full error output please?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the the parameter `@id` in your update query. Thats why you are getting the error:

> syntax error or column id does not exist

Just try the below code:

```
try
{ 
    conn.Open();
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    sql = "UPDATE public.demand SET city = @city, demand = @demand WHERE demand_id = @id";

    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", citytext.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demand", demandtext.Text.ToString());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Now check.. did you check the updated answer? Ive updated the demad parameter